# Choose option based on percentages from dictionary

Tags: java

I am relatively new to java and have been working on a program involving probability. Currently I am stuck at the point where I have a dictionary / map / hashMap that looks like this.

```
["Charlie":0.2,"Fred":0.1,"Ricky":0.5,"Damon":0.2]
```

From this I would like a function that has a 20% chance to choose charlie, 10% chance to choose Fred and so on...

I have no clue how to go about this, however. And am completely lost. Thanks for the help.

Edit: some extra information: I need it to be scalable as the list can vary in size. Also, it needs to only return one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this (I tested and it works):

```
String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
Double[] values = map.values().toArray(new Double[map.size()]);

for(int x=1; x<values.length; x++)
    values[x] += values[x-1];            //Accumulate probabilities

double rand = Math.random();
for(int x=0; x<values.length; x++){
    if(rand < values[x])
        System.out.println(keys[x]);
        break;
    }
```

---

**Explanation:**

Accumulate the probabilities for each name:

```
Charlie: 0.0-0.2
Fred:    0.2-0.3
Ricky:   0.3-0.8
Damon:   0.8-1.0
```

Then just roll a random number and check it falls into who's range. Ricky has a wider range than others (in this case, 50%), so it has 50% chance to be selected.

**First 15 runs:**

```
Fred
Ricky
Charlie
Ricky
Ricky
Damon
Charlie
Damon
Fred
Charlie
Fred
Charlie
Ricky
Ricky
Ricky
```

**Placing the code under 10 million runs:**

```
Charlie: 19.98881%
Fred:    10.014190000000001%
Rcicky:  50.00255%
Damon:   19.99445%
```

Comment: does this require that the list of values add up to 1, or can they be any number

Comment: @joshLor This doesn't work at all. The probabilities are biased.

Comment: @joshLor The description is correct, it's the same idea than in my answer, but the code is wrong. It does not check correctly into who's range the number falls - it generates a new random number for every check.

Comment: @alain then could I adapt it to generate the random number outside of for loop. Personally I just prefer for loops over while loops.

Comment: @joshLor The list of values have to add up to 1, because that is the probability for each name. Even if your school gives you a new dataset, the sum of values will always be 1 hence this code here can handle different datasets and it is correct.

Comment: @alain What do you mean by `"but the code is wrong. It does not check correctly into who's range the number falls - it generates a new random number for every check"` ?

Comment: You generate a new random number in every iteration of the `for(int x=0; x<values.length; x++)` loop. I'm not 100% sure that this results in biased results, but it seems odd. For example, if the first random is 0.9 and the second 0.1, it picks Fred, but Fred's range would be 0.2 - 0.3.

Comment: I think the probability for Fred is `0.8*0.3 = 0.24` with this algorithm, but it should be `0.1`

Comment: @alain If the first random number is 0.9 followed by 0.1. Damon and Charlie will be chosen respectively. Each random number generated is independent and not affected by previous runs. The probability of Fred is just 10%. Why do you multiply 0.8 to 0.3?

Comment: No! In `for(int x=0; x<values.length; x++)
    if(Math.random() < values[x]){` Math.random() gives a **new** random number after the first check (the check for Charlie).

Comment: @alain I get what you mean. I have updated and tested once again. It is correct now. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @user3437460 shouldn't random be between the range 0-sum(values)?

Answer (score 0):

- sort entries by probability level, using arrays for same level.
- pick one array randomly
- pick one people randomly in the array.

---

```
final SortedHasMap<Double, List<String>> people = new TreeMap<>();
people.put( 0.5, new String[]{"Ricky"});
people.put( 0.2, new String[]{"Charlie", "Damon"});
people.put( 0.1, new String[]{"Fred"});
final Random   r = new Random();
final double   l = r.nextDouble();
final String[] p = people.tailSet(l).first();
final String   e = p[(int)(p.length*r.nextDouble())];
```

Comment: Is this scalable? what if the *dictonary/map/hashMap* as mentioned in the question grow in size with more elements?

Comment: I think the OP wants to choose just *one* of the entries. But the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: ye sorry I fixed it i needs to be scalable and I need to choose just one of the entries.

Comment: Some structuration added.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two enumerations with the names and probabilities plus a random number generator `random`, which you should keep and not re-create on every call:

```
double r = random.nextDouble();
double sump = 0.0;
while(names.hasMoreElements() && probs.hasMoreElements()) {
    double p = probs.nextElement();
    String n = names.nextElement();
    if(r >= sump && r < sump + p)
        return n;
    sump += p;
}
```

The idea is to choose Charlie when 0.0 <= r < 0.2, Fred when 0.2 <= r < 0.3, and so on.